# sklearn RandomForestRegressor oob_score_ looks wrong?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am a newbie to datascience. I installed the Jupyter notebook and was trying to create model for the kaggle titanic dataset. Below is the code I wrote -

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import pandas as pd
X = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
y = X["Survived"]
X["Age"].fillna(X.Age.mean(),inplace = True)
numeric_variables = list(X.dtypes[X.dtypes != "object"].index)
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, oob_score = True, random_state = 42)
model.fit(X[numeric_variables],y)
model.oob_score_
```

I am getting the `oob_score_` output as 1.0 while the actual output as per tutorial should be 0.13420....
After that I did

```
y_oob = model.oob_prediction_
print "c,stat:", roc_auc_score(y,y_oob)
```

The output of this as well I am getting 1.0. Is there something wrong in my code or setup of Jupyter?

Comment: Could you please post the link to the tutorial as well? It is more likely that something is wrong with the code (or maybe data) and not with the Jupyter setup.

Comment: The question has nothing specifically to do with Jupyter. Just because you're running in Jupyter does not make it a Jupyter issue (and if you suspected that it was, just rerun in command-line Python to check it is/isn't). It's more relevant that it's an issue with sklearn, RandomForestRegressor and in particular `oob_score_` looking wrong, on this dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Random Forest Regressor, but since you have a binary response where a passenger survives or not, the Random Forest Classifier should be used.  If this doesn't fix the issue, please send the link to the tutorial.